# Firma por canvas

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo este código pero no consigo que dibuje correctamente no se porque.

```html
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>All Clientes</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css">
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <style>

        canvas{ border: 1px solid black; }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var canvas, ctx, flag = false,
                prevX = 0,
                currX = 0,
                prevY = 0,
                currY = 0,
                dot_flag = false;

        var x = "black",
                y = 2;

        function init() {
            canvas = document.getElementById('canvasFirma');
            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            w = canvas.width;
            h = canvas.height;

            canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
                findxy('move', e)
            }, false);
            canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
                findxy('down', e)
            }, false);
            canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
                findxy('up', e)
            }, false);
            canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
                findxy('out', e)
            }, false);
        }


        function draw() {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
            ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
            ctx.strokeStyle = x;
            ctx.lineWidth = y;
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
        }

        function erase() {
            var m = confirm("Want to clear");
            if (m) {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
                document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "none";
            }
        }

        function save() {
            document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.border = "2px solid";
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
            document.getElementById("canvasimg").src = dataURL;
            document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "inline";
        }

        function findxy(res, e) {
            if (res == 'down') {
                prevX = currX;
                prevY = currY;
                currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
                currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

                flag = true;
                dot_flag = true;
                if (dot_flag) {
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.fillStyle = x;
                    ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
                    ctx.closePath();
                    dot_flag = false;
                }
            }
            if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
                flag = false;
            }
            if (res == 'move') {
                if (flag) {
                    prevX = currX;
                    prevY = currY;
                    currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
                    currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
                    draw();
                }
            }
        }
    </script>

    <body onload="init()">
        <form method="POST" action="/guardar">
            <input type="hidden" th:value="${usuario.nombre}" name="nombre">
            <input type="hidden" th:value="${usuario.email}" name="correo">
            </br>  </br>
            <h1 class="text-center header">Datos empleado</h1>
            <div class="container my-2">
 <div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Guardar" name="Guardar" >
                    </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    Nombre:<p th:text="${usuario.nombre}"></p>
                    Email:<p th:text="${usuario.email}"></p>
                    <div class="contenedor" aling="center">
                        <h3 aling="center">Firma</h3>
                        <div class="row">                               
                            <div class="col-md-1" aling="center">
                                <canvas id="canvasFirma" aling="center" width="200" height="200" style="position:absolute;top:10%;left:10%;border:2px solid;"></canvas>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                   </div>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Qué es "dibujar correctamente"?

Comment: Prueba a limpiar de ese código todo lo que no es necesario para el problema actual, crea un [mcve] y será más sencillo encontrar el problema, tanto para ti como para nosotros

Comment: Tienes el html con el codigo javaScript menos de eso no se que ponerte

Comment: @jachguate pues donde yo pongo el razon no pina pinta mas abajo

Comment: Si creo que podría haber código de más, pero lo más importante sería explicar claramente qué resultado esperas, pues sin saber eso, no sabría decir qué tiene mal tu código, ni si está completo, o tiene de más!

Comment: @jachguate pues no se que tiene que explicar que donde yo cliquee pinte y no un metro mas abajo y si no se si sobre codigo no soy experto en JX

Comment: ¿O sea que hay que hacer clic en algún lugar? He hecho clic en varios lugares y no pinta nada, ni un metro más abajo ni en ningún lugar (quizás mi monitor es pequeño... :D)

Comment: @jachguate a ver es un lugar para firmaa mantiene el clic y arrastras para firmar y cuando quieras sueltas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utiliza las propiedades `offsetX` y `offsetY` del evento `e`.

La [documentación de `offsetX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetX) dice:

> The `offsetX` read-only property of the `MouseEvent` interface provides the offset in the X coordinate of the mouse pointer between that event and the padding edge of the target node

Mi traducción libre:

> La propiedad de solo lectura `offsetX` de la interface `MouseEvent` provee el corrimiento en la coordenada X del puntero del ratón entre el evento y el borde de relleno del nodo destino

```html
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>All Clientes</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css">
    </head>
    <style>

        canvas{ border: 1px solid black; }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var canvas, ctx, flag = false,
                prevX = 0,
                currX = 0,
                prevY = 0,
                currY = 0,
                dot_flag = false;

        var x = "black",
                y = 2;

        function init() {
            canvas = document.getElementById('canvasFirma');
            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            w = canvas.width;
            h = canvas.height;

            canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
                findxy('move', e)
            }, false);
            canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
                findxy('down', e)
            }, false);
            canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
                findxy('up', e)
            }, false);
            canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
                findxy('out', e)
            }, false);
        }


        function draw() {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
            ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
            ctx.strokeStyle = x;
            ctx.lineWidth = y;
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.closePath();
        }

        function erase() {
            var m = confirm("Want to clear");
            if (m) {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
                document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "none";
            }
        }

        function save() {
            document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.border = "2px solid";
            var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
            document.getElementById("canvasimg").src = dataURL;
            document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "inline";
        }

        function findxy(res, e) {
            if (res == 'down') {
                prevX = currX;
                prevY = currY;
                currX = e.offsetX;
                currY = e.offsetY;

                flag = true;
                dot_flag = true;
                if (dot_flag) {
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.fillStyle = x;
                    ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
                    ctx.closePath();
                    dot_flag = false;
                }
            }
            if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
                flag = false;
            }
            if (res == 'move') {
                if (flag) {
                    prevX = currX;
                    prevY = currY;
                    currX = e.offsetX;
                    currY = e.offsetY;
                    draw();
                }
            }
        }
    </script>

    <body onload="init()">
        <form method="POST" action="/guardar">
            <input type="hidden" th:value="${usuario.nombre}" name="nombre">
            <input type="hidden" th:value="${usuario.email}" name="correo">
            </br>  </br>
            <h1 class="text-center header">Datos empleado</h1>
            <div class="container my-2">
 <div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Guardar" name="Guardar" >
                    </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    Nombre:<p th:text="${usuario.nombre}"></p>
                    Email:<p th:text="${usuario.email}"></p>
                    <div class="contenedor" align="center">
                        <h3>Firma</h3>
                        <div class="row">                               
                            <div class="col-md-1" aling="center">
                                <canvas id="canvasFirma" align="center" width="500" height="350" style="position:absolute;top:10%;left:10%;border:2px solid"></canvas>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
                    </div>
                   </div>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Debes ajustar la coordenada en caso que el canvas tenga algún *padding*.

Más información sobre [_offsetX en w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_offsetx.asp) (en inglés).